# Radio Button - Reading Pre Selected Values From Db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, radio-button

I have a radio button which reads the value from mysql and highlights the correct radio button successfully. 
I also have jquery validation which when the radio button is at 'no' value the 2 dropdown menus are greyed out.

My problem lies in that when a user selects 'no' radio button it saves it to mysql but when he/she logs back in the radio button is at correctly at 'no' position however the 2 drop down menus are NOT greyed out as they should be. If i then click on the 'no' radio button they grey out.

I obviously do not want this, if a user selected 'no' then logs back in i want the dropdown menus to be greyed out on login.

php code:

```
<?php
$row2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($row2) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

RADIO BUTTON CODE:

```
       <input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes" <?php if($row3['attendance1']=="Yes") { echo "checked"; }?>/>Yes 
                 <br />
         <input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="No" value="No" <?php if($row3['attendance1']=="No") { echo "checked"; }?>/>No

I would be greatful if someone could tell me where i am going wrong. When retrieving the value from the database it is obviously not physically selecting the radio button which i would like it to do

JQUERY VALIDATION:

          <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         <script>      
            $( function(){    
                    function validate(id){       
                        var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');         
                        if(enabled){              
                            //Please select option is selected              
                            if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                 
                            alert('Please make your colour selection');                  
                            return false;             
                            }              
                            //Please select option is selected              
                            if($("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                  
                                alert('Please select your shade');                  
                                return false;             
                            } 


                        }     
                        return true;    
                    };

                    $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function() {  

                        var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');      
                        $("#colour" + id + ", #shade" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');         
                        validate(id);    
                    });      
                   $("input:submit").click(function(){         
                       var retVal = true;
                       $.each([1], function(i, val){
                          retVal = (validate(val) && retVal);
                       });
                        return retVal;   

$(document).ready(function(){    

$("input[name=attendance1]:checked").triggerHandler('click'); 
});     
</script>
```

two dropdowns are called colour and shade

Comment: Do you disable the drop downs from PHP or only in the JavaScript? You need to show more code.

Comment: I use a jquery. Have editted with source of jquery. I dont think the problem lies with the jquery as it works if I physically select 'no'. but when 'no' is imported from mysql it does not work until i click 'no' myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have jQuery trigger the onclick handler when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[name=attendance]:checked").triggerHandler('click');
});
```

So your total code would look something like:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>      
$( function(){    
    function validate(id){       
        var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');         
        if(enabled){              
            //Please select option is selected              
            if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                 
            alert('Please make your colour selection');                  
            return false;             
            }              
            //Please select option is selected              
            if($("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                  
                alert('Please select your shade');                  
                return false;             
            } 


        }     
        return true;    
    };

    $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function() {  

        var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');      
        $("#colour" + id + ", #shade" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');         
        validate(id);    
    });      
   $("input:submit").click(function(){         
       var retVal = true;
       $.each([1], function(i, val){
          retVal = (validate(val) && retVal);
       });
        return retVal;  
   });
});

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("input[name=attendance]:checked").triggerHandler('click'); 
});     

</script>
```

Comment: i tried this previously however it does not work for some reason :s

Comment: Where are you putting this in the code? Are you being sure to add it AFTER the click function as been bound?

Comment: sorry dont know about acceptance, new to this. I have edited my jquery above to show where i put it thanks

Comment: You should not re-include `<script src="jquery.js">`... this only needs to be added once

Comment: Also, I slightly modified by code. Remove the duplicate library inclusion and use the new code.

Comment: can you plz see my revised code. I did as you said however still having issues

Comment: Several errors now: 1. `input[name=attendance1]` has a `1` in it that doesn't belong. 2. Your functions aren't closing properly. Add this code outside the initial `$(` block or don't include the `$(document).ready(function(){ ` part. I've added the edited code to my answer.

Comment: worked thanks, one last thing before i mark your answer. if i was to add another attendance radio button called attendance1.
would code me be $("input[name=attendance, attendance1]:checked").triggerHandler('click');

Comment: I don't believe that syntax will work. Here's a guide on multiple selectors: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something along the lines of this in your `head` so it is automatically disabled when the page loads. I'm sure you can figure out an appropriate value for `id`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#colour" + id + ", #shade" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');
});
</script>
```

You could disable the drop downs from the PHP, but this is a bad idea because you will screw over people with JavaScript disabled.